# How con i change data value from a function?

Tags: vue.js, components

I want to change count variable every click. If i put "count++" in the on:clik event, it work. But, when i want to use a function doesn't do anythig.
I also tried to put the component and the "new view" in the same file js, but doesn't work and show a blank page,why? thanks

**Prova.js**

```
Vue.component('prova', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            count: 0
        }
    },
    template: '<div><button v-on:click="Add">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button></div>',
    methods:{
        Add: function(){
           prova.count++;
        }
    }

});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>prova component</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Prova.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<section id="prova">
    <prova ></prova>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#prova",
    })
</script>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `prova.count++` - there's no prova variable. It's supposed to be `this`, isn't it?

Comment: yes, it's the solution but idk why it didn't work the first time i tried.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I don't know what your second `component` is used to be, but you can solve your problem like this:

*In the template*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="addCount()"></button>
    <div>You have clicked the button {{count}} times.</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

• @click is the same like v-on:click

• you should write it like following: `addCount()`

*In the script:*

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addCount() {
      this.count += 1;
    }
  }
}
```

• define `count` in your data

• use methods and on every `click` on your button add 1 to the current value

This should solve your problem. Please give me a short feedback if this worked out for you!

**For little testing**: You can also subtract from `count`. Just create a second `button` and make another click event an there you use `this.count -= 1`. This will subtract 1 each time you click it.